# hiding the text of the checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list that I am binding it with the database. I want only the checkbox part to be visible, i don't want the items associated to be visbible so for e.g if I have three items in my checkbox list, i just want three text boxes visible and text part to be hidden.

Below is my code

```
 checkboxlist1.DataSource = RadListBox_selectedAssistAgency.Items; 
 checkboxlist1.DataBind();
```

Please let me know how can I acheive this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned a `DataTextField` property to your CheckboxList? Leaving that empty might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the text, a possible solution would be to hide the labels with css:

Css:

```
.noText label 
{
    display: none;
}
```

And in code behind, set the css class:

```
checkboxlist1.CssClass = "noText";
checkboxlist1.DataSource = RadListBox_selectedAssistAgency.Items; 
checkboxlist1.DataBind();
```

Or set the css class in the html-file:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlist1" runat="server" CssClass="noText">
```

---

Another possible solution is to remove the text from the items:

```
checkboxlist1.DataSource = RadListBox_selectedAssistAgency.Items; 
checkboxlist1.DataBind();

foreach (ListItem item in checkboxlist1.Items)
{
    item.Text = ""; // Set text to empty.
}
```