# How to add (hidden) label for asp:CheckBox?

Tags: asp.net, accessibility

I ran chrome's lighthouse accessibility test on a page I'm working on and it says

> Form elements do not have associated labels

for all the checkboxes used on the page.  They are in a large grid and have no labels.

Ex:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbNotApplicable" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbNotApplicable_CheckedChanged" onClick='javascript:needToConfirm = false;' ToolTip="Answer all questions Not Applicable" />
```

If I add a Text attribute, the accessibility warning goes away, but a `<label>` is added and visible, which I do not want.

[image]

Is there an alternate way to make the asp:CheckBox accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```html
    <asp:Label ID="test" runat="server"
        AssociatedControlID="cbNotApplicable"> <asp:CheckBox ID="cbNotApplicable" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cbNotApplicable_CheckedChanged"
     onClick='javascript:needToConfirm = false;' ToolTip="Answer all questions Not Applicable" /> </asp:Label>
```

Or, try this below link suggestions to hide label by using CSS

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482643/2218635

Comment: Your snippet worked, thank you!

I feel like it actually went against the spirit of the warning though, so i added an ```aria-label``` attribute to the Label.. hopefully that is the correct thing to do accessibility wise.